# Сортировка таблицы без обращения к БД. ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Доброго времени суток.

Коллеги, можно ли в ASP.NET MVC отсортировать список, которых содержит результат запроса к БД, повторно не обращаясь к БД без использования Session["..."] или Session - единственный способ сохранить данные в памяти сервера между запросами?

Comment: нет, не единственный, есть еще `Cache`, например. А почему нельзя в сессии?

Comment: Можно. Просто хотелось рассмотреть все варианты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При использовании Entity Framework можно попробовать использовать:

- .OrderByDescending(c => c.client_id).ThenBy(c => c.Person.Fullname);
- .clients.OrderBy(c => c.client_id).